# Implementation of biological model

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, cheminformatics

I need to do implementation to biology model ( it is applied the functions of organelle in living cell ) using biopython or any suitable programming language.
 I am beginner in this field.

What is suitable programming language for this problem? 
Can any one help me ?
How I can start?

Answer (score 0):

[KNIME](https://www.knime.com/) with its [cheminformatics extensions](https://www.knime.com/cheminformatics-extensions) is often used to model [chemical transformations](https://hub.knime.com/knime/spaces/Examples/latest/99_Community/03_RDKit/04_Chemical_Transformations).

Comment: I don't need to design model. I need to write code to implement my biology model.it is existed already

Comment: You can program within KNIME, see https://www.knime.com/developer-guide and https://www.knime.com/blog/to-code-or-not-to-code-is-that-the-question